# Выделение подмассива по индексам в VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Есть массив, например, a = [50, 33, 42, 17, 64, 29, 71], и массив индексов idx = [2,3,5]. Нужно выделить подмассив b = [33,42,64]. В матлабе это делается b = a(idx). А как это можно сделать в VBA?

Comment: А никак... в смысле - копируй в новый массив поэлементно.

Comment: Совет новичку. Не забывайте принимать ответы, которые вам подходят (кликайте на галочку).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub fun()
 Dim a, idx
 a = Array(50, 33, 42, 17, 64, 29, 71)
 idx = Array(2, 3, 5)
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim b() As Integer
 ReDim b(UBound(idx) - LBound(idx) + 1)
 Dim k As Integer
 k = LBound(b)
 For i = LBound(idx) To UBound(idx)
  b(k) = a(idx(i))
  k = k + 1
 Next i
 'здесь массив b заполнен
End Sub
```

Comment: Формально переменная k лишняя и прекрасно считается по значению переменной i... А зачем потребовалось делать массив назначения динамическим и устанавливать Option Base, я вообще не понял. Ну и уж коли пишете процедуру - надо было бы передавать параметры снаружи, а не устанавливать их внутри...

Comment: @Akina Option Base 1 для того, чтобы с помощью Array создать массив, указанный в вопросе (индексирование с 1). Без Option Base 1 Array создаст массив с индексированием от 0. Переменная к не лишняя, т. к. нижний индекс у массивов может отличаться. И здесь я привёл не готовое решение , готовое к внедрению в производство, а пример, из которого будет ясно, как решить вопрос.

Comment: Ну Вы же везде используете функцию получения границ массивов! что, кстати, при создании независимой функции очень правильно... так что глубоко сиренево, откуда начинается индексация... а `k = i-LBound(idx)+LBound(b)` - можете проверить...

Comment: @Akina Ну Вы же не будете спорить, что инкрементировать переменную гораздо дешевле и красивее, чем делать вызов двух функций для получения индекса?

Comment: Ну я не зря написал, что переменная лишняя "формально". Просто это дополнительный косвенный аргумент к тому, что Option Base походу не нужен...

Comment: @MindCleaner, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Не считать ответом. Скорее, дополнение (в комментариях нельзя вставить код нормально)

Если с применением *Option Base 1*, то

```
Sub fun2()
Dim a(), idx()
Dim i As Long
    a = Array(50, 33, 42, 17, 64, 29, 71)
    idx = Array(2, 3, 5)

    For i = 1 To UBound(idx)
        a(i) = a(idx(i)): Debug.Print a(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Результат складывается в исходный массив. При такой конструкции значения в *idx* должны быть расположены по возрастанию. Если нет, то применение еще одного массива оправдано.

В дальнейшем массив использовать до индекса *UBound(idx)* или *i-1*. Например:

```
Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, i - 1).Value = a
```